# Sencha 2 Routing with Deft JS

Tags: mobile, sencha-touch, deftjs

Does sencha touch 2 routing works with Deft JS ? I am extending my controllers with Deft.mvc.ViewController instead of Ext.app.Controller and looks like routing is not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't seem to be working: https://github.com/deftjs/DeftJS/issues/44

As a workaround I'd try to use DeftJS controllers as ViewControllers to control the logic of the app and ExtJS controllers as RouteControllers to work with routes. To separate them, put ViewControllers next to views and model as have been done in ExtJS 5. RouteControllers shall go to app/controllers directory.

Another option is to use Ext.ux.Router.